# Collection is not defined after a bare meteor install on windows 10

Tags: meteor, collections

This newly installed meteor (1.10.2) by chocolatey on windows 10 followed by `meteor create --bare appName` then copy/paste some 2 year old code I had parked for a while. Chassing the cause of this runtime error for no avail.

```
ReferenceError: DataTeckCol is not defined
at server/dataTeck.js:13:1
at module (server/dataTeck.js:20:8)
```

../server/dataTeck.js

```
"use strict";
let cheerio = require('cheerio');
import {Matcher} from "./matcher";
import {Dispatcher} from "./dispatcher";
import '../imports/api/dataTeck.js';

DataTeckCol.remove({plateNum: {$in: plates}});  //<<<<<<<< Error line
```

../imports/api/dataTeck.js

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const DataTeckCol = new Mongo.Collection('dataTeckCol');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly import the exported const, so instead of

```js
import '../imports/api/dataTeck.js';
```

you need to import it via

```js
import { DataTeckCol } from '../imports/api/dataTeck.js';
```

Comment: Does that mean every collection will need to be declared in it's own file under the api folder and every time it needs to be referenced, the import statement will need to be at the top of the file, is there an equally modular way that takes less typing and maintenance?

Comment: You can define it in global scope then you just need to import it once but global scope is an anti pattern. Your ide should automatically resolve the import when autocompleting the variable. With webstorm that works out of the box, with vs code you need to install a plug-in and then it works, too.